# MongoDB - Mongoose and Mongo Command Line Manipulation (Where does the DB save?)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With MongoDB and Mongoose where do the database files save? I have the below code running on my local node setup and I can't find the database when using the mongo shell. Please help.

```
# coffescipt: 

mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/testData');
db = mongoose.connection
db.once 'open', ->
  console.log 'Connected to MongoDB'

dataSchema = mongoose.Schema {type: String, success: Boolean}
Data = mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema)

talon = new Data {type: 'data', success: false}

talon.save (err, talon) ->
  console.log "#{talon.type} Added to DB"

Data.find (err, data) ->
  if err
    console.error 'No data found :('
  else
    console.log data
```

I've looked under all visible databases using `show dbs` and none of the data Mongoose has submitted is in any of them, however when Mongoose runs `Data.find (err, data) ->` it displays the full list of inserted documents.

I just want to be able to work with the database through the mongo command line, then use Mongoose to manipulate it for my web app.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data directory used by `mongod` can be provided on the command line with `--dbpath`. My guess is your install is using the default location, which varies by OS and distribution but in linux look under `/var` and `/var/lib` or on OSX with homebrew look under `/usr/local/var/lib`.

However, your problem is really not about where the data files live on disk, is getting a consistent connection to the same database server and same database name, which all comes from your connection URL. When you run the `mongo` shell, try providing a URL like `mongo localhost/testData`, which should make the code you have above.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, the problem was I had not read enough up on the Mongo Shell. Everything was workign fine.

The key was collections. `show collections` I was unfamiliar with them up until now. Still learning :)